# PHP, MYSQL - Query fails but no error meessage appears

Tags: php, mysql

Back again, thanks for all the help last time. I'm running this query:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM event where evLoc = ".$loc." AND evChar = ".$char;
 var_dump($query);
 $result = mysql_query($query, $con) or die('Error 1:'.mysql_error());
 if ($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die('Error 2:'.mysql_error());
    var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));
    exit();
```

I get a message Error 2: but no mysql_error printed out. The var_dump($query) printed out a query that ran without errors in phpMyAdmin. The var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result)) did not print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of being *too* cautious and applying error checking where it doesn't belong.

Don't call `die()` in partnership with a fetch call. The fetch intentionally returns FALSE when there are no rows available, so you don't have an error, just no rows.

```
// No rows were returned, wich is FALSE
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die('Error 2:'.mysql_error());
```

Instead, don't call `die()` here:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row) {
  // you got something
}
```

Or this way:

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // you got something.
}
```

If multiple rows are expected to be returned, fetch in a `while` loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // loops until you're out of rows
  // or not at all if you have no rows
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply Single Quotes in the fields of your query

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM event where evLoc = '".$loc."' AND evChar = '".$char."'";
```

You can write these in short form too. Like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event where evLoc = '$loc' AND evChar = '$char'";
```

Next, you might want to change your fetch portion.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
 ....
}
```

When you use this, you will avoid the error you would receive when no rows are returned.

Comment: I think you mean "you will avoid the error you would receive"

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your request returns 0 rows and mysql_fetch_array returns FALSE